# Excel 2013: copy then paste only the visible cells from the subtotals sheet

Tags: microsoft-excel-2013

Excel 2013: In my workbook I have a page which is subtotaled.  I want to copy then paste only the visible cells with the subtotals.  I could do it in 97-2003.

Answer (score 0):

Per the tip [here](http://excelribbon.tips.net/T010677_Copying_Subtotals.html):

1. Collapse to show only subtotals.
2. Select the subtotals you want to show.
3. Press **F5**
4. Click **Special...**, choose **Visible cells only** and click **OK**
5. Use Ctrl+C and Ctrl+V (or click the equivalent buttons) and only the selected subtotals will be copied.

Comment: Links can break any time, please see the help how to make good quality answers with link.